# Do sentences with stative verbs like "Bob hates apples" have the habitual aspect?

Tags: meaning

> Bob hates apples.
>
> hate - feel extreme aversion for or extreme hostility toward; detest

Does this mean, at the moment of speaking, that Bob is feeling a sensation of hatred? I have a feeling that it doesn't because that statement holds true when he is sleeping or feeling something else. However, does that instead mean that the sentence has the habitual aspect and that he habitually thinks about apples and thus habitually feels hatred towards apples?

Answer (score 3):

This describes a **characteristic** of Bob, and therefore is saying that at any given moment, if you asked him if he hates apples he will say "Yes, I do.".

It doesn't mean that he is in a constant state of feeling hatred for apples, however:  he doesn't (necessarily) wake up in the morning and think "OH GOD, I HATE APPLES SO MUCH!!!".  He's not sitting at his desk later on thinking "Goddamn all you f*cking apple b*stards".  It just means that's how he **generally** feels about them.

Also, when people talk about "hating" something, they quite often mean that they "dislike" that thing.  Hatred implies a strong negative emotional  reaction.  For example, Bob might genuinely HATE a politician:  when that person comes on the TV, Bob gets really angry, because he thinks that person has ruined, or will ruin, his life with their stupid policies.  But apples don't make Bob angry, he just dislikes the taste, or texture.  So, he's actually exaggerating when he says he hates them.

Comment: If he isn't feeling hatred at the moment of speaking but doesn't feel it habitually, then why does he feel hatred? If I say "Bob feels sick" then it means he feels sick at the moment of speaking, but if I say "Bob hates apples" it doesn't mean he feels hatred at the moment of speaking, and I was wondering why that's the case.

Comment: Technically, that **should** mean that at the moment of speaking he feels that he hates apples.  But it's complicated by the fact that people tend to exaggerate with the word "hate" when they're talking about food, and they don't actually hate it, they merely dislike it.  For example, i might tell someone that i hate celery, but what i really mean is if someone gives me some salad with celery in it i will tend to pick out the bits of celery and leave them on the side of the plate:  i don't get angry about it.  Bob **might** actually hate apples, but he probably doesn't.

Comment: The example would be simpler, in a way, if you'd picked something that people do actually genuinely hate, like Donald Trump.  Then you could ignore the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Okay, what if the sentence was something like "Bob hates Donald Trump"? Why doesn't it mean that Bob feels hatred at the moment of speaking yet also doesn't mean he feels the hatred habitually?

Comment: Well, it might, but it tends not to.  Bob might be spending every waking moment thinking "GODDAMN YOU TRUMP!".  But this would probably mean that he would quickly go insane, if he's not already:  imagine what it would be like to spend every waking moment thinking about how much you hate someone:  you would be in a kind of hell - it's not sustainable.  So, from a grammatical point of view, "Bob hates Donald Trump" might be equivalent to "The sun illuminates the earth", but pragmatically the meaning is very different.  I suppose the former is actually a simplification, and the latter isn't.